# Direct relation in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I'm a beginner in SQL and I'm trying to make a small database, but I was asked to make a direct relation between `OrderNumber` in `Orders` table and `CustomerNumber` in `Customers` table, aren't I using a direct relation in here?.

Here is my code:

**Customers** table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerNumber VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CustomerName   VARCHAR(50),
    Phone          INT NOT NULL,
    Country        VARCHAR(50),
    City           VARCHAR(50),
    State          VARCHAR(50),
    PostalCode     VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
```

**Orders** table:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderNumber    VARCHAR(25) ,
    CustomerNumber VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ProductName    VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    OrderDate      DATE NOT NULL,
    requiredDate   DATE NOT NULL,
    Status         VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: **WHY** is the `CustomerNumber` the primary key in `Orders` ?!?!? That doesn't make any sense at all ... `CustomerNumber` in `Orders` should be a **foreign key** to the `Customer` table - to establish that relation you're talking about ... Also, why is it called `Customer**Number**` but it's a `VARCHAR(25)` datatype?? Number = numeric - should be `INT` or something like that....

Comment: Columns that should contain only numbers should never be VARCHAR. ID's are typically integer numbers.

Comment: Do some research on the concept of foreign key constraints.

Comment: Jup, Orders.CustomerNumber should be a FOREIGN KEY that points to Customers.CustomerNumber

Comment: Here is some documentation on creating relationships between tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, you probably want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerNumber INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CustomerName   VARCHAR(50),
    Phone          INT NOT NULL,
    Country        VARCHAR(50),
    City           VARCHAR(50),
    State          VARCHAR(50),
    PostalCode     VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderNumber    INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CustomerNumber INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(CustomerNumber),
    ProductName    VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    OrderDate      DATE NOT NULL,
    requiredDate   DATE NOT NULL,
    Status         VARCHAR(50)
);
```

- Changed the datatype of `CustomerNumber` and `OrderNumber` to `INT`
- Made `Orders.CustomerNumber` a **foreign key** with a relation to the `Customer` table (`CustomerNumber` column)